# VBA Find (LookAt=xlWhole) will always return an error

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have a search function in a VBA code that searches column A. Column A is filled with acronyms and the corresponding rows in Column B are the meanings for that acronym.

I have a user form setup that the user can enter an acronym and if it is in the file, it will show a message box saying what that acronym means.

I am trying to search for an exact match of the acronym the user enters, via this line:

```
Range("A:A").Find(acro, LookAt = xlWhole).Select
```

However, when I run it, even if I copy a cell containing an acronym and paste it into the user form text box, it will act as if it could not find it and follows my On Error handle.

What did I do wrong that made it unable to find the acronym string I am looking for?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are running this code from the user form it's probably not looking in the proper range. Try specifying the sheet explicitly: `Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(acro, xlWhole).Select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@nwhaught already answered and pointed out the real issue, but to add something too large for a comment:

It's best not to chain Select/Activate directly to Find():

```
Range("A:A").Find(acro, LookAt = xlWhole).Select
```

...since that requires error handling when the item is not found (and as you discovered that can mask other issues with your code)

Try something like this instead:

```
Dim f
Set f = Range("A:A").Find(acro, LookAt := xlWhole)
If Not f Is Nothing then
     'do something with f
End If
```

The `Is Nothing` test avoids the use of error handling.

Comment: Thanks for the help in both my problem and for the guidance on avoiding error handling!

Comment: @nwhaught had the answer to the actual problem - you should give them the check mark...

Answer (score 2):

Your `On Error` handle is masking the true cause of the error.

Code should be `Range("A:A").Find(What:=acro, LookAt:= xlWhole).Select`

When debugging, it's best to disable error handling, as the whole point of handling an error is to mask its effect to the user. (which makes debugging nearly impossible)

Comment: Thank you, its good to know that error handling should be a last resort